# Entity Framework Code First Approach getting error : "The underlying provider failed on Open"

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to create a simple database with the Code First Approcah EF 5.0 .

I have Employee class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have EmployeeDbContext class:

```
public class EmployeeDbContext : DbContext
{
    static EmployeeDbContext()
    {            
        Database.SetInitializer<EmployeeDbContext>(null);
    }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And Repository class:

```
public class Repository
{
    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()        
    {            
        EmployeeDbContext MyDataBase = new EmployeeDbContext();
        return MyDataBase.Employees.ToList();
    }
}
```

i've created WebFrom file and a GridView Inside it and connected it with ObjectDataSource to the Repository (Screenshot):http://s3.postimg.org/jqvm89scz/Capture.png

This is my ConnectionString :

```
    <add name="EmployeeDbContext" connectionString="server=.; Database=Sample;Trusted_Connection=True; Persist Security Info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When i debug this Im getting this error on the "return MyDataBase.Employees.ToList();"

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in
 EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.
```

I've tried to add before this line this `MyDataBase.Database.Connection.Open();` and got this error:

```
Cannot open database "Sample" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

**UPDATE**

When i change the Database in the ConnectionString to an exisiting one (Northwind Database) its working, im just mention again that im trying to create a database that doesnt exist.

Comment: Did you try to connect to the database with the connectionString of yours? new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDb2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

Comment: sorry didnt understand, what should i do?

Comment: Ok yeah, that update make all the difference, never tested that

Comment: its look like he trying to open the "Sample" database but from what i understand is that in the code first approach he should create the database from the code, so what im missing? where should i tell him to create the database and not try to open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. Some connection strings samples are listed on this page.
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

You can test your connection string in code with something like this (this shlould not throw an exception) without any EF stuff.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"your connection string"))
{
  connection.Open();
}
```

Comment: I've tried almost all Connection string combinations

Comment: Can you connect to your db with vs and list all tables. Or with sql management studio? I don't see any user or pw in your connection string.

Comment: As i said in the update , when i changed the database to exist one it worked and i saw the table of employees in the northwind database without user and password, what im trying to do is to create a new database

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx ?

Comment: Well, it is a bit difficult to connect to a database that does not exist.

Comment: ThankYou ! ! ! the SetInitializer did that !